# How to initialize a static field marked with ThreadStaticAttribute for each new thread from the thread pool?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I have a field which marked with the `ThreadStaticAttribute`. It is initialized in the main thread, but my code uses a lot of `async/await` constructions and `Parallel` library that is why I don't know how many threads will execute. I want to make sure that each thread will have this field initialized. How can I do it?

Comment: You can initialize it on first access (that is - you want to read value, see field is not initialized yet - initialize it).

Comment: @Evk Are there any ways to initialize it before accessing?

Comment: I don't think so. Actually initializing it is discouraged, as docs state: "Do not specify initial values for fields marked with ThreadStaticAttribute, because such initialization occurs only once, when the class constructor executes, and therefore affects only one thread". You can use `ThreadLocal<T>` to do what you want, I think.

Comment: There is also an ``AsyncLocal<T>`` class which might be worth a look.

Comment: @Evk: Would a "singleton-like" initialization not solve the OP's problem (initializing before accessing) without using a direct initialization?

Comment: @Flater I think that is what I suggested in first comment. Still it requires to first check the value of field (to see if it is already initialized), but for some reason OP wants to avoid that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `ThreadStaticAttribute` you cannot perform initialization in a way you want. Actully, documentation states that you should not perform any initialization at all:

> Do not specify initial values for fields marked with
>   ThreadStaticAttribute, because such initialization occurs only once,
>   when the class constructor executes, and therefore affects only one
>   thread

You can however use the alternative: `ThreadLocal<T>`:

```
 private ThreadLocal<string> _myVar = new ThreadLocal<string>(() => "some string");

 var s = _myVar.Value; // separate for each thread
 _myVar.Value = "changed";
```

Note that `ThreadLocal<T>` implements `IDisposable` and so must be disposed when you are done with it.

You can also implement separate accessor for `ThreadStatic` field which will first check if field is initialized and if not - initialize it, then return value (similar to singleton pattern). It is thread safe to do without any locks because of `ThreadStatic` field.

Also note that using `ThreadStatic` or `ThreadLocal` with thread-pool threads (like you do) might lead to surprising behavior, because local thread storage is not cleaned when thread is returned to the pool. So you might "start" a new thread (while really thread is taked out of the pool) and that thread might already have value in `ThreadStatic``ThreadLocal` field left from previous iteration.